# Injecting Custom JavaScript Into React Native's Webview

Tags: react-native

I want to inject javascript codes to injectedJavaScript method of react native web view. I could inject one javascript code working fine but multiple can't. Is there any trick to do that?

```
  injectedJavaScript={`document.querySelector('.header-wrapper').style.display='none' ` }
```

this works.

But i want something like this to inject multiple javasript things but not work.

```
let  jsCode = `(
               function() {

                document.querySelector('.footer').style.display='none' ;
                document.querySelector('.tabs').style.display='none' ;
                document.querySelector('.header-wrapper').style.display='none' ;
                document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.margin-top=-70px ;

              })();`;

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
      source={{uri: 'blabla.com'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
        injectJavaScript={jsCode}
        javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
      />
    );
  }
```

When i try this i am getting unexpected token etc. How could i inject multiple javascripts to react native web view ? Thanks in advance.

Full code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {





  render() {

  return (
      <WebView
      source={{uri: 'https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily?geo=TR'}}
      injectedJavaScript={`document.querySelector('.trending-searches-footer').style.display='none';`
      + ` document.querySelector('.content-header-buttons daily-header-buttons').style.display='none'; `
       + `  document.querySelector('.trending-feed-tabs').style.display='none'; `
      + ` document.querySelector('.header-wrapper').style.display='none'; `
      + ` document.querySelector('.trending-feed-page-wrapper').style.marginTop='-70px'; `
      }
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
          ref="WEBVIEW_REF"
      />
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your javascript, this would cause the script to fail:

```
document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.margin-top=-70px; // this is wrong syntax
```

try this

```
document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.marginTop='-70px';
```

To use it with injectedJavascript write your script as you would if it was one line, it doesn't make any difference, but you should make sure that your javascript doesn't have any errors:

```
let  jsCode = `
    document.querySelector('.footer').style.display='none';
    document.querySelector('.tabs').style.display='none';
    document.querySelector('.header-wrapper').style.display='none';
    document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.marginTop='-70px';
 `;
```

And the use injectedJavaScript and not injectJavaScript to use it.

```
<WebView
  source={{uri: 'blabla.com'}}
  style={{marginTop: 20}}
  injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
  javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you i didn't realize that . But how could i use injectedJavaScript for multiple javascript codes? It accepts only one . injectJavaScript works for multiples but it works before load view . Can i call injectJavaScript at onLoadEnd ? or how could i do that ?

Comment: ı have tried     injectedJavaScript={document.querySelector('.trending-searches-footer').style.display='none';
    + document.querySelector('.content-header-buttons daily-header-buttons').style.display='none';
      + document.querySelector('.trending-feed-tabs').style.display='none';
        + document.querySelector('.header-wrapper').style.display='none';
          + document.querySelector('.trending-feed-page-wrapper').style.marginTop='-70px';
      } this but it works first line other lines not working.

Comment: can you try it like in my updated answer and see if it works? If the script doesn't have any errors it should work. If you can share the url you load maybe I debug this better :)

Comment: i've updated my question upon your request. i shared full code . Sorry for edit your comment . I did by mistake.

Comment: Ah, I think I get the problem now :). You are trying to access elements that are not on the page you're loading. There is no elements with class "footer", "tabs" and "wrapper", I only see an element with class "header-wrapper", that is why this is the only line of your code that works.  You should check the html of the page you are loading and find the correct classes of the elements you want to hide.

Comment: No sir at first i wrote like "footer tabs" etc  for briefing code . Actual code like trending-searches-footer as İ refered as Full code : section with last edit. Can u check full code section again plz. I have checked all one by one all works.All are correct classes.The problem is can't concatenate all of them.It just works first one.Others ignoring.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://snack.expo.io/rJeQcbCK7 I think it works as you want

Comment: Thank you sooo muchh . now i needsleep too :D

Comment: Haha! Doesn't everyone??